# How to run multiple independent pipelines in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have created two very similar pipelines:

```
- pipeline.id: ERP_PROD
  pipeline.workers: 1
  queue.type: persisted
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/ERP_PROD.conf"

- pipeline.id: ERP_DEV
  pipeline.workers: 1
  queue.type: persisted
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/ERP_DEV.conf"
```

he .conf files differ only in two parameters input.path and filter.translate.dictionary_path one looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^{%{DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG}"
      what => "previous"
      negate => true
    }
    path => "/var/data/1CLog/ERP_PROD/1Cv8Log/*.lgp"
    ignore_older => "432000"
    sincedb_path => "/etc/logstash/file_input_tracking/ERP_PROD.sincedb"
    start_position => "beginning"
    stat_interval => 120
    type => "ERP_PROD"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "host", "@version", "@timestamp" ]
    rename => [ "type", "Database" ]
  }
  grok {
    match => [ "message", '{%{DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG:Date},%{DATA:StatusTransaction},{%{DATA:Transaction},%{DATA:NumberTransaction}},%{INT:UserId},%{INT:ComputerId},%{INT:NameApplicationId},%{INT:Connection},%{INT:EventId},%{DATA:Importance},\"%{DATA:Comment}\",%{INT:MetadataId},{\"%{WORD:ArrayDataType}\",\"%{DATA:Data1}\"},\"%{DATA:RepresentationData}\",%{INT:WorkServerId},%{INT:MainIpPort},%{INT:SecondIpPort},%{INT:Session},%{INT:MoreMetadata}' ]
  }
  translate {
    source => "[UserId]"
    target => "[User]"
    dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/ERP_PROD_.yml"
    refresh_interval => 104
    fallback => "Nothing to match!"
  }
}

output {
  opensearch {
      hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
      user => "logstash"
    password => "**********"
      index => "log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   }
}
```

I'm afraid that the filter may trigger on both data at the same time, because I don't check input.type.

Can you tell me if I need to add input.type checking or if the different pipelines are independent and don't know anything about each other?

Comment: You need to explain how you are starting logstash. If you are setting -f on the command pointing to /etc/logstash/conf.d, or setting that in logstash.yml then logstash will combine the two .conf files and run all the events through both filters and outputs. If logstash is reading pipelines.yml to start two independent pipelines then they will be independent.